# (Probability) How many tosses to cook n slices on both sides with probability > 85%

Tags: probability

i'm having problem solving this question as I am not really sure where to start and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, thanks.

Here is the question:

Q) With n slices of bacon in a pain, how often do you have to toss such that all sides are cooked (100% of the slices are cooked on both sides) with a probability of >85%

The question also tells me to find the general formula for n and then try it for n=10 and n=100, thank you for your time.

Comment: There isn't enough definition to this problem - we have no idea what it takes for bacon to be cooked, nor what "tossing" does.

Comment: I'm guessing it means when a toss is performed it lands on a given side, once this side lands then that side of the bacon is cooked. I presume the question is asking me how many times with n slices how many tosses are needed to have n slices land on each side.

Comment: And is the probability of landing on each side equal to $50$ percent?

Comment: That would be my guess, too, but the question is very badly stated if there is no preamble to the question giving this information.

Comment: Yea I presume the probability landing on either side is 50 percent, thank you for trying to help me though guys. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose each toss flips a piece of bacon with probability $\frac 1 2$ and that you remove pieces that are cooked on both sides. Then after $t$ tosses probability that a single piece has not flipped is $(1/2)^t$ hence probability that all were flipped is $p=(1-(1/2)^t)^n$. Solve $p>0.85$ for $t$.